# CMake: Visual Studio 15 2017 could not find any instance of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

When I am trying to install CMake I get the error:

```
Visual Studio 15 2017 could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2017. The `CMakeOutput.log` file writes:

```
The system is: Windows - 6.1.7601 - AMD64
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 184):

I ran into the same error and performed the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Go to Tools -> Get Tools and Features
3. In the "Workloads" tab enable "Desktop development with C++"
4. Click Modify at the bottom right

These steps resulted in the "Visual C++ tools for CMake" feature being installed, but the other optional C++ features included in this workload may also helpful for what you are trying to do.

After the Visual Studio updater finishes installing try re-running the command. You may need to open a new command window.

Comment: That was it. I've had most of the C++ stuff, but the "Visual C++ tools for CMake" were missing. Thank you.

Comment: I have installed it, but still getting the error. I'm not sure but maybe it is related to uninstalled cmake 3.12 and then installed 3.13

Comment: I installed Visual Studio 2019 with all those settings enabled and still getting this error. Have the latest cmake version (3.16.5), which should be fine given the recommendation for a lower version and above for cmake in the installer of VS itself.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015, there is no menu Tools -> Get Tools and Features.

Comment: There is no "Visual C++ tools for CMake" feature option in Visual Studio 2022. In fact, searching for "CMake" in the components list doesn't have any results.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, I installed Visual Studio, selecting the workloads and modules that I wanted, but I ignored the request to reboot, assuming that shutting down the computer at the end of the day and restarting it the following day would suffice. *I was wrong.*

The following day I tried a cmake build and got the "**could not find any instance of Visual Studio**" error. After several attempts to resolve, I re-ran the installer, made no changes to the configuration, and clicked Modify. This time I let it reboot the computer. The reboot took a long time. After which my cmake build worked.

Answer (score 11):

If you have already installed the workload `Desktop development with C++` and still getting the following errors while using visual studio 2022 for flutter

```
Generator

Visual Studio 16 2019

could not find any instance of Visual Studio.

Building Windows application...

Exception: Unable to generate build files"
```

**Solution**: Follow these steps,

1. Edit `your_flutter_path\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\windows\build_windows.dart`, and change the constant on line 28 from `Visual Studio 16 2019` to `Visual Studio 17 2022`
2. Delete `flutter_tools.stamp` and `flutter_tools.snapshot` from `your_flutter_path\bin\cache\`
3. Run `flutter clean` in the project

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue "*could not find any instance of Visual Studio*"
but with Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition) and I just had to configure the `VS160COMNTOOLS` variable so that CMake correctly detects Visual Studio.

```
export VS160COMNTOOLS="/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/Tools"
```

(cf https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html)

With Visual Studio 15 2017, the variable you need should be `VS150COMNTOOLS`.
(cf https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2015%202017.html)

NB: in my case, in a Travis-CI workflow, I installed Visual Studio using the commands (no need to reboot):

```
choco install visualstudio2019community
choco install visualstudio2019-workload-nativedesktop # required
```

With only the first package, CMake detection of VS2019 failed.

Answer (score 3):

I was configuring a Jenkins build node and could successfully run CMake GUI manually but command line use or builds using the CMake plugin would fail with:

Visual Studio 16 2019 could not find instance of Visual Studio.

`-A x64` parameter was added with no change in result.

The problem was that CMake could not determine the Windows SDK version.

By adding `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION` parameter CMake was then able to find Visual Studio:

```
-D CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0.18362.0
```

(use your windows SDK version)

Environment:
windows 10 system build: 19042
CMAKE 3.19.4
VS 2019 Professional 16.8.4
Jenkins 2.235.1

Full command line that worked:

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake" -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -A x64 -D CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0.18362.0
```

Comment: How can we determine SDK version dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

When using VS 2017, be aware that this is really VS 2015, and CMake identified it as VS 2017 2022 which is not the version of VS 2017 I had, that gave me this error.  So the conclusion I offer is to try different versions, specifically the 2015 one.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the Visual Studio 2019(my former one is 2017 version ) with all those settings required(my cmake version is 3.23.0),and it works. So try to install different versions.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was gone after I deleted the previous cmake result directory and then ran cmake again.

Answer (score 1):

For those of us that don't use VS IDE and only use the build tools make sure to check `C++ - CMake tools for Windows`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed two or more Windows 10 SDK, delete them excluding latest one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where installing libzmq in my npm project was throwing the same error and that wasn't getting solved by enabling "msbuild" under "Desktop development with C++" in the Visual Studio installer.

My solution ended up being to reinstall the Windows build tools for npm with the following command.

`npm install --global windows-build-tools`

Note: Remember to run the command prompt (or whatever terminal you are using) as admin before running this.

Answer (score 0):

If the CMake used to work with the installed Visual Studio and is broken someday, then the problem could be VS requires system reboot to complete some update.

For quick verification, rename `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\Reboot` to like `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\Reboot.bak`, then re-run cmake which should succeed. Don't forget to rename the registry back and reboot the system if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was selecting different version of visual studio in that configuration dialog box whereas I installed different version.
Do select the same version.

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions did not solve this issue for me. After installing node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ apparently a correct version of windows-build-tools was installed

Comment: If above solution is removed as answer your answer should include the key essentials to understand what was going on "back then". End of Review.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue on Visual Studio Code and have the visual c++ tools for CMake installed. You might still need to select the right kit:

Press Ctrl+Shift+p and type `CMake: Select a Kit` and hit enter. You can then select the right version that is installed.

Answer (score -1):

**Try downloading the windows-build-tools package.**

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2015
```

This step should be the end-all-be-all solution to fixing node-gyp problems. For most people, that’s true. NPM has a package called windows-build-tools that should automatically install everything you need to get node-gyp working, including the Microsoft build tools, compilers, Python, and everything else required to build native Node modules on Windows.