# Unable to install NodeGui and React-NodeGUI in Windows10

Tags: node.js, qt, npm, cmake, desktop

Environment:
Windows 10
Python 2.7
node 12.8.1
VisualStudio 2017 with cc++ desktop development
Below is the logs which i got it while executig npm install
Logs
{
PS D:\ReactNodeGUI> git clone https://github.com/nodegui/nodegui-starter                                          Cloning into 'nodegui-starter'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 47, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (47/47), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (345/345), 275.78 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas:  74% (176/236)used 16 (delta 14), pack-reused 298 esolving deltas:   0% (0/236)
Resolving deltas: 100% (236/236), done.
PS D:\ReactNodeGUI> cd .\nodegui-starter\                                                                         PS D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter> npm install
> @nodegui/qode@2.1.0 postinstall D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules@nodegui\qode
> node install.js

```
    Cached archive already exists at C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\qode-nodejs\Cache\qode-win32-x64-v2.1.0.tar.gz. Skipping download....
    Extracting C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\qode-nodejs\Cache\qode-win32-x64-v2.1.0.tar.gz to D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\qode\binaries ...
    Qode was setup successfully at : D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\qode\binaries

    > @nodegui/nodegui@0.22.0 postinstall D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui
    > cross-env npm run setupqt && (node ./scripts/skip.js || npm run prebuild:install || npm run build:addon)


    > @nodegui/nodegui@0.22.0 setupqt D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui
    > cross-env node ./scripts/setupMiniQt.js

    Minimal Qt 5.14.1 setup:
    Archive already exists at C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\nodegui-mini-qt-nodejs\Cache\5.14.1-0-202001240957qttools-Windows-Windows_10-MSVC2017-Windows-Windows_10-X86_64.7z. Skipping download....
    Extracting C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\nodegui-mini-qt-nodejs\Cache\5.14.1-0-202001240957qttools-Windows-Windows_10-MSVC2017-Windows-Windows_10-X86_64.7z to D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\miniqt ...
    Archive already exists at C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\nodegui-mini-qt-nodejs\Cache\5.14.1-0-202001240957qtbase-Windows-Windows_10-MSVC2017-Windows-Windows_10-X86_64.7z. Skipping download....
    Extracting C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\nodegui-mini-qt-nodejs\Cache\5.14.1-0-202001240957qtbase-Windows-Windows_10-MSVC2017-Windows-Windows_10-X86_64.7z to D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\miniqt ...
    Qt Tools for Minimal Qt: 5.14.1 installation was setup successfully.  outDir: D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\miniqt
    Qt Base for Minimal Qt: 5.14.1 installation was setup successfully.  outDir: D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\miniqt

    > @nodegui/nodegui@0.22.0 prebuild:install D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui
    > prebuild-install --backend=cmake-js --runtime=napi --verbose

    prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 5.3.4
    prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\e5c5c6-nodegui-v0.22.0-napi-v3-win32-x64.tar.gz
    prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/nodegui/nodegui/releases/download/v0.22.0/nodegui-v0.22.0-napi-v3-win32-x64.tar.gz
    prebuild-install http 404 https://github.com/nodegui/nodegui/releases/download/v0.22.0/nodegui-v0.22.0-napi-v3-win32-x64.tar.gz
    prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=3 runtime=napi arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! @nodegui/nodegui@0.22.0 prebuild:install: `prebuild-install --backend=cmake-js --runtime=napi --verbose`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the @nodegui/nodegui@0.22.0 prebuild:install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-07T05_04_04_563Z-debug.log

    > @nodegui/nodegui@0.22.0 build:addon D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui
    > cross-env CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL=8 cmake-js compile

    [
      'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
      'D:\\ReactNodeGUI\\nodegui-starter\\node_modules\\cmake-js\\bin\\cmake-js',
      'compile'
    ]
    info TOOL Using Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 generator.
    info CMD CONFIGURE
    info RUN cmake "D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui" --no-warn-unused-cli -G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_JS_VERSION="6.1.0" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build" -DCMAKE_JS_INC="C:\Users\hp\.cmake-js\node-x64\v12.18.1\include\node;D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\nan" -DCMAKE_JS_SRC="D:/ReactNodeGUI/nodegui-starter/node_modules/cmake-js/lib/cpp/win_delay_load_hook.cc" -DNODE_RUNTIME="node" -DNODE_RUNTIMEVERSION="12.18.1" -DNODE_ARCH="x64" -DCMAKE_JS_LIB="C:\Users\hp\.cmake-js\node-x64\v12.18.1\win-x64\node.lib" -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="/DELAYLOAD:NODE.EXE"
    Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27041.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27041.0
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe - skipped
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe - skipped
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Using QT installation for nodegui_core QT_CMAKE_HOME_DIR:D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\miniqt\5.14.1\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5
    -- Using Qode installation for nodegui_core QODE_BINARY_DIR:D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\qode\binaries
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: D:/ReactNodeGUI/nodegui-starter/node_modules/@nodegui/nodegui/build
    info CMD BUILD
info RUN cmake --build "D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build" --config Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Checking Build System
  Automatic MOC and UIC for target nodegui_core
  Building Custom Rule D:/ReactNodeGUI/nodegui-starter/node_modules/@nodegui/nodegui/CMakeLists.txt
  mocs_compilation.cpp
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  main.cpp
  nutils.cpp
  integration.cpp
  flexutils.cpp
  flexlayout.cpp
  flexitem.cpp
  nodestyle.cpp
  eventsmap.cpp
  eventwidget.cpp
  yogawidget.cpp
  log.cpp
  Utils.cpp
  YGConfig.cpp
  YGEnums.cpp
  YGLayout.cpp
  YGNode.cpp
  YGNodePrint.cpp
  YGStyle.cpp
  YGValue.cpp
  Yoga.cpp
  event.cpp
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\include\deps\yoga\Yoga.cpp(3220): warning C
4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\nod
e_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\include\deps\yoga\Yoga.cpp(3257): warning C
4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\nod
e_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\include\deps\yoga\Yoga.cpp(3257): warning C
4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_
modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
  experiments.cpp
  qbrush_wrap.cpp
  qpen_wrap.cpp
  qcolor_wrap.cpp
  qapplication_wrap.cpp
  qclipboard_wrap.cpp
  qkeyevent_wrap.cpp
  qmouseevent_wrap.cpp
  qfontdatabase_wrap.cpp
  qpicture_wrap.cpp
  qpixmap_wrap.cpp
  qicon_wrap.cpp
  qfont_wrap.cpp
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\lib\QtGui\QPixmap\qpixmap_wrap.cpp(78): war
ning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starte
r\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\lib\QtGui\QPixmap\qpixmap_wrap.cpp(81): war
ning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starte
r\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
  qcursor_wrap.cpp
  qkeysequence_wrap.cpp
  qmovie_wrap.cpp
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\main.cpp : fatal error C1128: number of sec
tions exceeded object file format limit: compile with /bigobj [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@node
gui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\lib\QtGui\QMovie\qmovie_wrap.cpp(85): warni
ng C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\n
ode_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\lib\QtGui\QMovie\qmovie_wrap.cpp(171): warn
ing C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\
node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
cl : Command line error D8040: error creating or communicating with child process [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starte
r\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
info REP Build has been failed, trying to do a full rebuild.
info CMD CLEAN
info RUN cmake -E remove_directory "D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build"
info CMD CONFIGURE
info RUN cmake "D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui" --no-warn-unused-cli -G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_JS_VERSION="6.1.0" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build" -DCMAKE_JS_INC="C:\Users\hp\.cmake-js\node-x64\v12.18.1\include\node;D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\nan" -DCMAKE_JS_SRC="D:/ReactNodeGUI/nodegui-starter/node_modules/cmake-js/lib/cpp/win_delay_load_hook.cc" -DNODE_RUNTIME="node" -DNODE_RUNTIMEVERSION="12.18.1" -DNODE_ARCH="x64" -DCMAKE_JS_LIB="C:\Users\hp\.cmake-js\node-x64\v12.18.1\win-x64\node.lib" -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="/DELAYLOAD:NODE.EXE"
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27041.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27041.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using QT installation for nodegui_core QT_CMAKE_HOME_DIR:D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\miniqt\5.14.1\msvc2017_64\lib\cmake\Qt5
-- Using Qode installation for nodegui_core QODE_BINARY_DIR:D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\qode\binaries
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/ReactNodeGUI/nodegui-starter/node_modules/@nodegui/nodegui/build
info CMD BUILD
info RUN cmake --build "D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build" --config Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Checking Build System
  Automatic MOC and UIC for target nodegui_core
  Building Custom Rule D:/ReactNodeGUI/nodegui-starter/node_modules/@nodegui/nodegui/CMakeLists.txt
  mocs_compilation.cpp
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  main.cpp
  nutils.cpp
  integration.cpp
  flexutils.cpp
  flexlayout.cpp
  flexitem.cpp
  nodestyle.cpp
  eventsmap.cpp
  eventwidget.cpp
  yogawidget.cpp
  log.cpp
  Utils.cpp
  YGConfig.cpp
  YGEnums.cpp
  YGLayout.cpp
  YGNode.cpp
  YGNodePrint.cpp
  YGStyle.cpp
  YGValue.cpp
  Yoga.cpp
  event.cpp
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\include\deps\yoga\Yoga.cpp(3220): warning C
4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\nod
e_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\include\deps\yoga\Yoga.cpp(3257): warning C
4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\nod
e_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\include\deps\yoga\Yoga.cpp(3257): warning C
4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_
modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
  experiments.cpp
  qbrush_wrap.cpp
  qpen_wrap.cpp
  qcolor_wrap.cpp
  qapplication_wrap.cpp
  qclipboard_wrap.cpp
  qkeyevent_wrap.cpp
  qmouseevent_wrap.cpp
  qfontdatabase_wrap.cpp
  qpicture_wrap.cpp
  qpixmap_wrap.cpp
  qicon_wrap.cpp
  qfont_wrap.cpp
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\lib\QtGui\QPixmap\qpixmap_wrap.cpp(78): war
ning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starte
r\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\lib\QtGui\QPixmap\qpixmap_wrap.cpp(81): war
ning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starte
r\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
  qcursor_wrap.cpp
  qkeysequence_wrap.cpp
  qmovie_wrap.cpp
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\main.cpp : fatal error C1128: number of sec
tions exceeded object file format limit: compile with /bigobj [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@node
gui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\lib\QtGui\QMovie\qmovie_wrap.cpp(85): warni
ng C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\n
ode_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\src\cpp\lib\QtGui\QMovie\qmovie_wrap.cpp(171): warn
ing C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter\
node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
cl : Command line error D8040: error creating or communicating with child process [D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starte
r\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\nodegui_core.vcxproj]
ERR! OMG Process terminated: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @nodegui/nodegui@0.22.0 build:addon: `cross-env CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL=8 cmake-js compile`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @nodegui/nodegui@0.22.0 build:addon script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-07T05_08_03_716Z-debug.log
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @nodegui/nodegui@0.22.0 postinstall: `cross-env npm run setupqt && (node ./scripts/skip.js || npm run prebuild:install || npm run build:addon)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @nodegui/nodegui@0.22.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-07T05_08_06_476Z-debug.log
PS D:\ReactNodeGUI\nodegui-starter> C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-07T05_08_06_476Z-debug.log
```

}

Comment: "Below is the logs which i got it while executig npm install" - You seems to forgot provide the logs.

Comment: Thanks Tsyvaerv, logs available , format was wrong sorry for this.

Comment: Please, do NOT use *blockquote* formatting for the logs. This formatting loses newlines and result is completely a trash. Paste the logs again, and format them as a code (with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and here are what I did to resolve it, some steps may not be necessary but I am not sure which one is critical:

1. remove and reinstall node.js (with all recommended additional things that I previously did not install such as python, visual studio build tools 2017...)
2. install cmake from https://cmake.org/
3. add 'Desktop development with C++' to Visual studio 2019 (previously installed) according to this [CMake: Visual Studio 15 2017 could not find any instance of Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668676/cmake-visual-studio-15-2017-could-not-find-any-instance-of-visual-studio)

Then it worked! I think steps 2,3 are important.