# error while building db grid file using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, griddb

I am following this link [griddb cclient]
[1](https://github.com/griddb/c_client)

and building file using cmake at E:/griddb/c_client/client/c/sample

But it shows following error

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):   Generator
>
> ```
> Visual Studio 17 2022
> ```
>
> could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
>
> Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "C:/Program
> Files/CMake/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

and in log file:

The log files shows

> The system is: Windows - 6.3.9600 - x86

Comment: Have you checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668676/cmake-visual-studio-15-2017-could-not-find-any-instance-of-visual-studio) about the similar error message? What have you tried from its answers?

Comment: Perhaps the obvious question: do you have Visual Studio installed and if so which version?