# How to install python module polaris (gives pyarrow installation error)

Tags: python, c++, apache-arrow, python-polars

I was going through some articles about how to make pandas run faster and found one of the alternatives polaris. I went to their github documentation and tried to install the module.

I am running windows10 and have installed [rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install).

Notes:

```
 python -c """import sys; print(sys.version)"""
3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]

python -c """import sys; print(sys.platform)"""
win32 # this is interesting, I thought my windows10 is 64-bit?


rustc --version
rustc 1.65.0 (897e37553 2022-11-02)


python --version
Python 3.11.0

and also I have Visual Studio code 2022 
 C\:/Program\ Files/CMake/bin/cmake --version
cmake version 3.24.0

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

## Installation code

```
pip install 'polars[all]'
```

## Error

```bash
.....
.....
\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 390, in spawn
          spawn(cmd, search_path, dry_run=self.dry_run)
        File "C:\Users\a126291\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-q2kfg6vo\overlay
\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\spawn.py", line 38, in spawn
          log.info(subprocess.list2cmdline(cmd))
      Message: 'cmake -DARROW_BUILD_DIR=build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -DCMAKE
_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\\Users\\a126291\\AppData\\Local\\T
emp\\pip-install-z34b9m08\\pyarrow_e72f6907c8c34d73add7f6887f9ba9b4\\build\\dist
 "-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\a126291\\OneDrive - AmerisourceBergen(ABC)\\ven
v\\py311pol\\Scripts\\python.exe" "-DPython3_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\a126291\\OneD
rive - AmerisourceBergen(ABC)\\venv\\py311pol\\Scripts\\python.exe" -DPYARROW_CX
XFLAGS= -DPYARROW_WITH_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_WITH_PARQUET_ENCRYPTION=off -DPYARR
OW_WITH_HDFS=off -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" C:\\Users\\a126291\\AppData\\L
ocal\\Temp\\pip-install-z34b9m08\\pyarrow_e72f6907c8c34d73add7f6887f9ba9b4\\pyar
row/src'
      Arguments: ()
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:53 (project):
        Generator

          Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

        could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/a126291/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-z34b9m08/pyarrow
_e72f6907c8c34d73add7f6887f9ba9b4/build/cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      -- Running CMake for PyArrow C++
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.exe' failed with exit
 code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit
h pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyprojec
t.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668676/cmake-visual-studio-15-2017-could-not-find-any-instance-of-visual-studio

Comment: I will take a look at these links.

Comment: Please note that `polars` does not require PyArrow to function per se, although some functionality comes via PyArrow. `pip install polars` should work. I would suggest to try that first, and see if you actually need PyArrow at all. The error you are getting is because you on Python 3.11, and PyArrow does not provide wheels for 3.11 yet. So it falls back to compiling from source directly.